# Percent of percent chain

Tags: percentages

Start out with a number, for example 458.

The number is reduced by 1% 35 times, so:

- 458
- 453.42
- 448.89
- ...
- 322.18

How can I calculate final number without doing a step-wise reduction?

Comment: Take $458\cdot (0.99)^{35}$, since $a-0.01\cdot a=0.99\cdot a$.

Comment: Reducing a number $x$ by $p%$ exactly $n$ times gives the number $(1-\frac{p}{100})^n\times x$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hint: If you multiply $x$ by $a$, the result is
$$
xa
$$
If you again multiply it by $a$, the result becomes
$$
xa^2
$$
If you again multiply it by $a$, the result becomes
$$
xa^3
$$
Can you see the pattern?